# Android GPS Speed Alert

Tags: java, android, performance, gps, location

I am creating a speed alert app & Im stuck at one point in the creation.
I have the speed being displayed properly but the set speed in which i need an alert to go of is not working.
I think i have placed the code in the wrong spot.
my code is:

```
if( insetSpeed > intspeed);
{
    Toast.makeText(speedalert.this, "Over Speed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

all variable have been converted to the same type int.

just the placement of the above code is required.

Many Thanks :D

**EDIT**

```
public void updateSpeed(Location location)
{
 float gpsSpeed = 0;

if( location!=null )
{ 
  gpsSpeed = ((location.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);
}

intspeed = (int)gpsSpeed;

TextView intSpeedTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intSpeedTV);
intSpeedTV.setText(String.valueOf(strCurrentSpeed));

TextView SpeedTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.SpeedTextView);

SpeedTextView.setText(String.valueOf(intspeed))

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
if (location != null)
{
  Location myLocation = new Location(location);
  this.updateSpeed(myLocation);

  }
}

public void speedAlert(Location location)
{
  if( intspeed >= 2) ;
    {   
        Toast.makeText(SpeedAlert.this, "Over Speed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Rewrote the code:

```
public class SpeedAlert extends Activity 
{
    NumberPicker np;
    int setSpeed;
    String strsetSpeed;
    int intspeed;
    int intsetSpeed;
    LocationListener LocLis;
    LocationManager LocMan;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.speedalertmain);

    LocMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    LocLis = new GetSpeeed(); 
    LocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0, LocLis); 


    np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    final TextView setSpeedTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setSpeedTV);


    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setMaxValue(160);
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

    np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String New = "";

            setSpeedTV.setText(New.concat(String.valueOf(newVal)));
            newVal = setSpeed;
            intsetSpeed = Integer.valueOf(setSpeed);
            }
    });
  }

  private class GetSpeeed implements LocationListener   
  {
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      if(location!=null) { 
          float gpsSpeed = 0;
            if(location.hasSpeed()){ 

            gpsSpeed = ((location.getSpeed()*3600)/1000);

            intspeed = (int)gpsSpeed;

            TextView SpeedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SpeedTextView);
            SpeedTextView.setText(String.valueOf(intspeed));

            TextView intSpeedTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intSpeedTV);
            intSpeedTV.setText(String.valueOf(intspeed));

            if( intspeed >= intsetSpeed) ;
            {   
                Toast.makeText(SpeedAlert.this, "Over Speed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            } 
          } 
       }

  }

}
```

Comment: Your above code does make sense, please post more code so we can all make a better validation of what you are trying to achieve and why it's not working.

Comment: thank you for the reply updated main post with code

Comment: Why does the method `speedAlert` need a Location object?  And why does the `onLocationChanged` method create a new object called `myLocation`, can't it just call `updateSpeed(location)` (and `speedAlert()` )? Also, think about speed units earlier rather than later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you have posted, I believe you are not calling your `public void speedAlert(Location location)`. I would suggest you update your `public void onLocationChanged(Location location)` like so:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
if (location != null)
{
  // Do you have to create a new Location instance?
  Location myLocation = new Location(location);
  this.updateSpeed(myLocation);
  this.speedAlert(myLocation);

  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I have tried that. Not been successful. as soon as the gps gets a fix it displays the toast. im going to update my orginal post with an updated code. I really want to get this sorted out its really frustrating. Thanks for all your help :D